# I'd better get a quart

Tags: infinitives, semi-modals

> I'**d better** get a quart. ([daum.net](http://dic.daum.net/search.do?q=%27d%20better&t=example&dic=eng))

There’s a *had better* usage in the above. I’m not trying to figure out what the original it would have been, but can this construction below be made? (When *I*, the main verb, is logically the object of the non-finite verb - *get*, it could be thought as a [tough movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tough_movement). But it's not the case.)

> I’d be better to get a quart.

Comment: Well, you'd be better getting a quart, or else you'd not be better off. :))

Comment: *Had better/best* is a modal idiom.  *Had* can be contracted to *'d* (or dropped entirely in very informal registers).  You can't rephrase it as *had be better*.  I don't understand what you mean by "the original".

Comment: That daum.net place looks like a rather whacky place to learn English, don't you think?  (Reminds me of a posted note on a German want-ad billboard in a cafe: "Learn you English with me?")

Comment: There's info about the idiom "had better/best" in the 2002 *CGEL*, page 113 [61] and page 196 [45].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean to change it to a question, or to ask if the following is sensible?

> I'd be better to get a quart.

If you said that to me I could respond by making a quizzical face and say:

> "I'd be better to get a quart?"

*(...as a challenge to the fact that I didn't understand what you just said, because it sounds weird.)*

Yet it could pass for old-timey pirate language, as a sort of short-hand for *"I'd be better off if I were to get a quart."*

> **first mate:** "Cap'N, would you like me fetch ye a gallon of skunk whiskey?"
>
> **cap'n:** "Arrr, nay!  I'd be better to get a quart of yonder Basil Hayden."

If you spoke like that people would know what you mean (and that you were a pirate).  But it's not normal speech, and you should go with *"I'd better get a quart."*...assuming you live in a place where people know what quarts are.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not a question. I deleted the question mark.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid not. This is actually a ‘fossilized’ expression with a long and complex history, summarized by [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/oed01arch#page/832/mode/2up) as follows:

> In the idiomatic *I, we, you, he,* etc. *had better*, the original construction was *me, us,* etc. *were betere* (or *bet*) = it would be more advantageous for me, etc. [...] The dat. pronoun was subsequently changed into the nominative, *I, we, were better* (perh. because in sbs. the two cases were no longer distinguished). Finally this was given up for the current *I had better* = I should have or hold it better, to do, etc. (Mr. F. Hall has shown that in these changes *better* followed in the main the analogy of *liefer* and *rather*.)<sup>†</sup>

It is really pretty hopeless to try to force this idiom into the straitjacket of conventional syntax, much less try to rephrase it with conventional transformations. It is what it is.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Mr. F. Hall is the 19th-century philologist [Fitzedward Hall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitzedward_Hall), an obsessive scholar of whom the *OED*’s first editor wrote that ‘When the Dictionary is finished, no man will have contributed to its illustrative wealth so much as Fitzward Hall’. His essay [‘On the Origin of “Had Rather Go” and Analogous or Apparently Analogous Locutions”](https://archive.org/stream/jstor-287026/287026#page/n1/mode/2up), *American Journal of Philology*, II.7 (1881) is delightful reading, not merely for the substance and copious documentation but chiefly for its wickedly acid remarks on attempts by earlier grammarians to make sense of this construction.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I agree with HostileFork, especially the pirate comment, but if you feel a burning desire to use "be better" you would say:

**It would be better to get a quart.**

That is, it would be better {for me and all concerned} to get a quart.

Someone who knows how much your friends like to drink might say:

**You would do well to get a quart, not a pint.**

Answer (score 2):

There's a bit of difference in meaning between the 2, and I don't think the 2nd is something you'd be likely to hear.

> I'd better get a quart.

It's preferable that I get a quart under the given circumstances (whatever they happen to be). This may prevent some unforeseen negative consequence in the future that could affect anybody.

> I’d be better to get a quart.

It would personally improve *me* and make *me* better if I got a quart. This version doesn't really make sense and sounds incorrect.

> I’d be better off getting a quart.
>
> I'd do better to get a quart.

These are both equally acceptable options, though again the focus shifts from the situation to the speaker. I'd be better off with a quart because of the positive outcome for *me,* or the aversion of a negative outcome for me personally.

Answer (score 1):

"I’d be better to get a quart" does not sound natural to my (American) ear.

"I'd be better off getting a quart" does sound natural to me.

In both of these examples, "I'd" is short for "I would".