# when to use "had better"

Tags: modal-verbs, semi-modals

I need your help.

I have the following three statements:

> People **should** unplug toasters before they clean them.
>   You **should have** unplugged the toaster before you tried to clean it.
>   You **had better** unplug the toaster before you try to clean it.

the first one is in the present , the second one is in the past , the third one is in the future, my question is how the third one is in the future while **had** is in the past

Comment: "had better" is an idiom. The "had" does not have a past time meaning--it has a modal remoteness meaning. (*CGEL* page 113.)

Comment: I'd use "had better" if I want to threaten someone!

Answer (score 3):

As MARamezani points out, *had better* is used to warn the hearer of some threat, and to suggest a way of avoiding it. The threat may be posed by the speaker or by some external agency. The exact nature of the danger may be expressed with either an *if* clause or a coordinate clause conjoined with  *or* + a negative or with *unless*:

> You had better unplug the toaster if you don't want a nasty shock.
>   You had better unplug the toaster, or you may get a nasty shock.
>   You had better unplug the toaster, unless you want a nasty shock.

But the consequence of not performing the action suggested does not have to be stated explictly; and when the speaker uses the idiom to threaten a hearer it is often left unstated, to allow the hearer to imagine what horrible thing might happen:

> You'd better not touch those cookies!

The *had better* is not in the past tense; as F.E. points out, this past form of the verb signifies 'modal remoteness' ('subjunctive' or 'irrealis' mood) rather than tense. (As explained [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/38990/32), the idiom goes all the way back to Old English, when the language still had subjunctive forms, and originally employed the subjunctive form of *BE*, not *HAVE*.)

It's not in the future tense, either: it is a *present* assessment of a possible future situation, and of a future action you might take in order to dispel that threat.